# C# & XAML how to get button to respond on first click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I actually got the bulk of my code to work. I appreciate the input, it pointed me in the correct direction. The problem I am having now is getting the buttons to work on the first click.

I appreciate any input that would help me improve my code.

Below are my XAML (MainPage.xaml) & C# (MainPage.xaml.cs) code.

```
<Page
x:Class="Calculator_Application.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Calculator_Application"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_title" TextWrapping="Wrap"     Text="Calculator Application" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="252" Margin="86,30,0,0" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.039,0.549" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FFBCB7B6"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_info" Content="Information" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="135,561,0,0" Click="button_Click" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Foreground="#FFF05D5D"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox_number1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,191,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="textBox_number1_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox_number2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,387,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please input numbers to calculate:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="252" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="29,134,0,0" SelectionChanged="textBlock_info_SelectionChanged" Foreground="#FFE5957F"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_add" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="29,278,0,0" MinWidth="25" Height="20" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Width="39" Background="Black"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_subtract" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="106,278,0,0" MinWidth="25" Height="20" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Width="39"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_multiply" Content="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="179,278,0,0" MinWidth="25" Height="20" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Width="39"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_divide" Content="/" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="257,278,0,0" MinWidth="25" Height="20" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Width="39"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_equals" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="=" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="38" Margin="164,387,0,0" FontSize="36"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_answer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="answer" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Width="139" Margin="207,387,0,230" FontSize="22"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is the C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
// Added to ensure popup is availible
using Windows.UI.Popups;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641


namespace Calculator_Application
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private double valHolder1 = 0;
    private double valHolder2 = 0;
    private double answer = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

        // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
        // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
        // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
        // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
        // this event is handled for you.
    }

    private void textBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void textBlock_info_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating instance for the MessageDialog Class  
        //and passing the message in it's Constructor  
        MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Page Lynn Potter, MBL 410, 05-15-2017, Robin Deitsch");
        //Calling the Show method of MessageDialog class  
        //which will show the MessageBox  
        await msgbox.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void textBox_number1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure out text box has a value
        if (textBox_number1.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            //Assign the value in text box to holder
            valHolder1 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number1.Text);
            //Empty the text box          
            textBox_number1.Text = string.Empty;

            if (textBox_number2.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                //Assign the value in text box to holder
                valHolder2 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number2.Text);
                //Empty the text box          
                textBox_number2.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //Calculate answer
            answer = valHolder1 + valHolder2;
            //Assign answer to text block
            textBlock_answer.Text = answer.ToString();
        }
     }

    private void button_subtract_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure out text box has a value
        if (textBox_number1.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            //Assign the value in text box to holder
            valHolder1 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number1.Text);
            //Empty the text box          
            textBox_number1.Text = string.Empty;

            if (textBox_number2.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                //Assign the value in text box to holder
                valHolder2 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number2.Text);
                //Empty the text box          
                textBox_number2.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //Calculate answer
            answer = valHolder1 - valHolder2;
            //Assign answer to text block
            textBlock_answer.Text = answer.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button_multiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure out text box has a value
        if (textBox_number1.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            //Assign the value in text box to holder
            valHolder1 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number1.Text);
            //Empty the text box          
            textBox_number1.Text = string.Empty;

            if (textBox_number2.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                //Assign the value in text box to holder
                valHolder2 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number2.Text);
                //Empty the text box          
                textBox_number2.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //Calculate answer
            answer = valHolder1 * valHolder2;
            //Assign answer to text block
            textBlock_answer.Text = answer.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button_divide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Make sure out text box has a value
        if (textBox_number1.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            //Assign the value in text box to holder
            valHolder1 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number1.Text);
            //Empty the text box          
            textBox_number1.Text = string.Empty;

            if (textBox_number2.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                //Assign the value in text box to holder
                valHolder2 = System.Double.Parse(textBox_number2.Text);
                //Empty the text box          
                textBox_number2.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //Calculate answer
            answer = valHolder1 / valHolder2;
            //Assign answer to text block
            textBlock_answer.Text = answer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an appropriate source for tutorial information, which is what you need here. Go read any of the many tutorials available describing the WPF API and how to use it. Your first step will be to get comfortable keeping your data separate from your UI, through the use of "view model" data structures, which have public properties that are bound to UI element properties for display. You'll also want to learn about `ICommand`, how to implement and bind to a `Button.Command` property, to handle user input for your calculator's buttons.

Comment: You better use MVVM. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: As said above, it will be good if you use MVVM, WPF, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand. there are few things you need to read before jumping to code.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a tutorial, just a step in the right direction. I never asked for you to code for me. I am simply just looking for resources to help me grasp a better concept on C# and XAML. Like I mentioned, I appreciate the input (whether it be good or bad). I will definitely look into MVVM and some of the other things mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You  have an event handler configured for the **button_info** button.

```
<Button x:Name="button_info" Content="Information" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Margin="135,561,0,0" 
        FontFamily="Global User Interface" Foreground="#FFF05D5D"
        Click="button_Click"/>
```

I don't see where you've configured handlers for the other buttons.

There should be something like this in the XAML.

```
<Button x:Name="button_add" Click = "button_add_Click" />
<Button x:Name="button_subtract" Click = "button_subtract_Click"   />  
<Button x:Name="button_multiply" Click = "button_multiply_Click" />
<Button x:Name="button_divide"Click = "button_divide_Click" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go ahead and add the event handlers. I must have forgotten to put them in and completely overlooked them. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I double checked my code and the event handlers are there now, but the button still needs to be clicked twice for it to put my answer in the answer textblock. Is it because I am using the emulator or did I still miss something?